# Network Issues ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, ping, ip-address

I have a question in regards to network connectivity. I have a mac mini that is running ubuntu server 14.04 and I'm have difficulty not only using apt-get to update and download but for some reason when I started up the machine today and started working it wouldn't let me ping a ip address. It says "connect: Network is unreachable". I've tried going into the interfaces file and changing around my settings in there but nothing has worked. I set up a static IP address along with specified my network, net mask, and gateway:

address 192.168.0.231
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.44
gateway 192.168.0.1

I'm not sure what to do here because everything I've tried either tells me I can't because of permissions and when I go to root it doesn't work.

Comment: can you add the entire `/etc/network/interfaces` file please.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your network setting should likely be 192.168.0.0 as the beginning of your address range given your network mask of 255.255.255.0. So that setting may be off.

That being said, if you use:
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.231 netmask 255.255.255.0

Where eth0 is your desired network adapter.

And follow with the command:
sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 eth0

That should create the correct settings. You may need to get rid of or alter the setting in your /etc/network/interfaces file to make 192.168.0.44 say 192.168.0.0.

Also, take care doing this remotely as you may lose connectivity changing network settings over the network. I've done it. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a static IP address, you are also responsible to declare DNS nameservers. I suggest your file be set up as:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.0.231
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: So I added this stuff to the file but when I put in sudo if down eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0 and i got this response: ifdown: interface eth0 not configured  Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)  run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d  run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool  run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools  run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant  ip addr add 192.168.0.231/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255  Cannot find device "eth0" Failed to bring up eth0.

Comment: Please edit your question to add: ifconfig. Perhaps your ethernet needs a driver.